# where can I find a elisp function

Tags: emacs, eshell

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EshellAlias

Hi I'm looking for a elisp function 'regexp-count-capture-groups'
at the end of this page.
Is there anyone who knows where this is or can write very similar codes?